# How do I detect orientation change for a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, orientation, fragment, orientation-changes

I am in a process of developing an Android app which have a activity and many fragments to that activity. I want to check and change the orientation of only two fragments among the many.

How do I do this? I want only these two fragments to change their orientation and not all. I came to know that we have to use OrientationEventListener for this, but I have no idea how to use this.

I am working on mobile device app and with Android 2.2 and fragment support files.

I went through the following links but made no reference to fragments:
[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html).

Comment: [This link](http://www.broculos.net/en/article/android-101-use-fragments-handle-different-screen-orientations) was supplied below in a link-only answer. That may be deleted in the future, so I will put it here.